# Checking if CheckBoxList has any selected values

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I would like to know the fastest/easiest way to check if a CheckBoxList control has any checked items or not, I'm talking about an entire checkbox list as a whole, not a single checkbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one should help:

```
bool isAnySelected = checkBoxList.Items.Any(i => i.Selected);
```

`.Any` is a Linq extension method, so you will need the `System.Linq` or `.System.Linq.Extensions` reference (can't remember which) in your code-behind.

Answer (score 19):

The Linq extension method is neat, but you can also just check the SelectedIndex:

```
bool isAnySelected = CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex != -1;
```

If nothing is checked, the SelectedIndex is -1.

Comment: should be the selected answer

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here 5 years after the selected answer, the Items collection is not enumerable therefore `.Any(...)` will not work. You can, however, do the following:

```
If cblCheckboxList.Items.Cast(Of ListItem).Any(Function(x) x.Selected) then...
```

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is great but now you can simply modify the code by adding **OfType** function. check the following:

```
bool isAnySelected = checkBoxList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Any(i => 
i.Selected);
```

I hope this helps.