# any easy way to check if no items has been selected in a checkboxlist control?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, checkboxlist

I know I can loop through a `checkboxlist.Items` and see if none of them is selected, but is there a better way to find out if no items have been selected, in the code behind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if CheckBoxList has any selected values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486847/checking-if-checkboxlist-has-any-selected-values)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check the SelectedIndex. If it equals -1, its means nothing is selected.

```
 CheckBoxList list = new CheckBoxList();
 if (list.SelectedIndex == -1)
 {
      //Nothing is selected
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) has properties for **SelectedIndex** and **SelectedValue**.

You can check whether there is a SelectedIndex; it will be -1 if no items are checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest way to validate the CheckBoxList:

Use a custom validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvmodulelist" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateModuleList" ErrorMessage="Please Select Atleast one Module"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Create a JavaScript function to validate the CheckBoxList:

```
// javascript to add to your aspx page
function ValidateModuleList(source, args)
{
  var chkListModules= document.getElementById ('<%= chkModuleList.ClientID %>');
  var chkListinputs = chkListModules.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0;i<chkListinputs .length;i++)
  {
    if (chkListinputs [i].checked)
    {
      args.IsValid = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Another option is to create a custom validation control, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CustomValidators
{
  public class RequiredFieldValidatorForCheckBoxLists : System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator 
  {
     private ListControl _listctrl;

     public RequiredFieldValidatorForCheckBoxLists()
     {
       base.EnableClientScript = false;
     }

     protected override bool ControlPropertiesValid()
     {
       Control ctrl = FindControl(ControlToValidate);

       if (ctrl != null) 
       {
         _listctrl = (ListControl) ctrl;
         return (_listctrl != null);   
       }
       else 
         return false;  // raise exception
     }

     protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
     {     
       return _listctrl.SelectedIndex != -1;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check selected index. If selected index is -1 it means that no item is being selected.

```
if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
     Response.Write("<script> alert('Show your message') </script>");
}
```